Run different apis project under one main project
I have total 5 API project in one solution and one main project, please see below image.
Now what I want is when I run that main project then it should start this all APIs project also.
So if I start MainTestAPI project then it should start all Test1.API, Test2.API and so on.

Right now all APIs projects are running on different ports.
So what I want is when I run that main project so it should run all APIS in one single port, like this below.
https://localhost:8080/api/test1/swagger/index.html
https://localhost:8080/api/test2/swagger/index.html
https://localhost:8080/api/test3/swagger/index.html

I am ok to make changes in startup.cs file OR launchsettings file of main project.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

You can set multiple startup projects for your solution either within Visual Studio or from docker-compose if you're using Docker.
Regarding running your other API projects on the same port, as these are separate processes there will be a conflict and so won't work. A common approach in such scenarios would be to implement an API gateway which proxies incoming requests to the desired API.
A couple of popular packages are Ocelot and YARP.

I can use docker, so should I need to pass all project names while using docker-compose command so it will run all projects together ?

@SamiIn - Use docker-compose to orchestrate your API services, here is an example. Then you can use a Docker profile to spin everything up.
